# Session is NULL Memcached - Codeigniter + Ratchet

Tags: php, symfony, session, memcached, ratchet

I have just installed Memcached and used some tutorials to set up the server.

This is my code for the server:

```
use Ratchet\Session\SessionProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

$memcached = new Memcached;
$memcached->addServer('0.0.0.0', 11211);

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8080', $loop); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\Session\SessionProvider(
            new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                    $pusher
                )
            ),new Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler($memcached)
        ) 
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

And onOpen function:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
$this->clients->attach($conn);
$this->users[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;
    var_dump($conn->Session->all());
    echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
}
```

Var dump output:

```
array(0) {
}
```

My problem is I can not get data send to memcached in Ratchet onOpen function.
I need this to send message to a particular user. I want to add database user ID to connection.

I have changed the code many times because I found more tutorials trying to fix the error but now I have no idea what to do next.
Memcached seems to work well, I can get data from memcached when I login in ssh.

I want to say now I am working on Codeigniter, it would be a better decision to move all code on Symfony?

Any advice will help!
Thanks!